# Can a braided fusion category have an order-2 Morita equivalence class which cannot be simultaneously connected and isomorphic to its opposite?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, fusion-categories, braided-tensor-categories, morita-equivalence

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a braided fusion category over $\mathbb{C}$. Let me write $\mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$ for the set of isomorphism classes of unital associative algebra objects in $\mathcal{B}$, and $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{B}) = \mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{B})/\sim_M$ for the set of Morita equivalence classes. These sets are naturally associative (but usually noncommutative) monoids under the tensor product operation. (The formula for multiplication in a tensor product of algebra objects explicitly references the braiding in $\mathcal{B}$.)

An algebra $X \in \mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$ is called *connected* if the unit object $1\in\mathcal{B}$ appears with multiplicity $1$ in the direct sum decomposition of (the underlying object of) $\mathcal{B}$. Every simple separable algebra is Morita equivalent to a connected one: given a separable algebra $X \in \mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$, you choose a simple $X$-module, and consider its algebra of endomorphisms.

Every algebra object $X \in \mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$ has an *opposite* algebra $X^{\mathrm{op}}$ — the formula for multiplication in $X^{\mathrm{op}}$ uses the braiding in $\mathcal{B}$. An algebra $X$ is called *Azumaya* if its Morita equivalence class $[X] \in \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{B})$ is invertible. If $X$ is Azumaya, then $[X]^{-1}$ is the Morita-equivalence class of $X^\mathrm{op}$.

I am interested in Azumaya algebras which are Morita self-dual in the sense that $[X] = [X]^{-1} \in \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{B})$, or in other words there exists a Morita equivalence $X \sim_M X^{\mathrm{op}}$. One way this can occur, of course, is if $X$ is isomorphic as an algebra to $X^{\mathrm{op}}$. Let's call such an algebra *antiautomorphic*. Every Morita self-dual algebra is Morita equivalent to an antiautomorphic one: what you do is to look at the category of $X$-modules; to take a direct sum of all simple $X$-modules, with each isomorphism class appearing with multiplicity one; and take the endomorphism algebra of this sum.

This universal representative, however, will typically fail to be connected. On the other hand, I don't know very many examples, and in the examples I do know, I can always find an antiautomorphic connected representative of each self-dual Azumaya class.

> What is an example of a braided fusion category $\mathcal{B}$ and an order-2 element in $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{B})$ which has no representative that is simultaneously connected and antiautomorphic?

Comment: Let me check I've correctly translated from algebras to module categories.  You're looking for a module category (which we think of as a bimodule category using the braiding) which has order 2 in Pic(B), but where none of the simple objects in the module category are "self-dual."

Comment: There's a confusing subtlety   Usually the dual of an object in a bimodule category lives in the inverse bimodule category, but since the bimodule is its own inverse you can think of the dual as living in the original category.  But this means talking about self-dual objects requires fixing the identification between the bimodule and the dual.  So if there's non-trivial invertible objects in B life gets confusing (which isn't surprising because it makes the relationship between objects in the module category and algebras in the original category many-to-one).

Comment: @NoahSnyder Yes, it seems that I am asking for an order-2 B-module category such for every identification of it with its dual, all simples fail to be self-dual.